# What's not right with my custom mouse acceleration registry edit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, windows-registry, charts

Basically, what I'm trying to do is tweak the Windows mouse acceleration so it lowers my non-gaming mouse's speed from 1000 DPI to 400 DPI. I've come into this solution and using a special graph editor software (Custom Curve). It worked on my system but when I tried actually writing it to Registry instead of using that software's driver, it made my mouse not move at all.

Here's the .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse]
"SmoothMouseXCurve"=hex:\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SmoothMouseYCurve"=hex:\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  94,5e,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  94,5e,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  94,5e,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  94,5e,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Here's the software's graph editor:

[image]

Here's the other software that I used to write the values to Registry:

[image]

Saving those values to a .reg file gave me the text above, why is it making my mouse not move at all but the other software with its own driver make my mouse move perfectly in the expected way (speed decrement only)? I do not want to keep the software that offers a curve editor as it comes with an external driver to control my mouse plus it only applies the changes after I run it.

Comment: Why do you have `SmoothMouseXCurve` all zeroes? AFAIK, this degrades your mouse acceleration graph…

Comment: Just realized something, the mouse acceleration curve system uses "sensitivity" but the Registry uses distance traveled per x and not sensitivity. That's what my issue is, I'll try to find workarounds.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://superuser.com/questions/278362/windows-mouse-acceleration-curve-smoothmousexcurve-and-smoothmouseycurve).

Comment: @JosefZ thank you, I already took a look at that and tried using the information to produce another .reg file which also didn't seem to work.